# TypeError: _node_modules_countdown_lib_lib__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3___default.a is not a constructor

Tags: typescript, webpack, import, export, es6-modules

I am working on my first ever npm package. A simple class that facilitates a countdown from a specified date using UNIX time. I have my webpack build working, and i have a local installation of the npm module set up with npm link for testing. However when i install the npm module on a local project for testing i get this error:

*

> **TypeError: _node_modules_countdown_lib_lib__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3___default.a is not a constructor**

*

**Webpack Config:**

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './src/index.ts',
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  plugins: [new CleanWebpackPlugin()],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: ['/node_modules/'],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'index.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'lib'),
    publicPath: '/',
    globalObject: 'this',
  },
};
```

**tsconfig:**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./lib",
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "lib"]
}
```

**Import statement in test project:**

```
import Countdown from "../node_modules/countdown-lib/lib";
```

**class definition and export (no constructor)**

```
export default class Countdown {}
```